# Mac Development - How to test against older versions of OSX?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have a mac app that is experiencing a weird bug that only occurs on older versions of osx. I'm running yosemite on my development machine and can't reproduce the issue.

It is a UI bug (dropdown panel not expanding to correct height) and so there is no crash report to help pinpoint the issue.

How can I test against older versions of osx? I can't find any settings within xcode to do this and I'm trying to spin up a VM but it is a P.I.T.A because I have to run an older version of xcode (which causes all sorts of problems with opening the project, xibs, etc).

Help?

Comment: @Andy Hin, Why do you have to open the Xcode project in the VM? Build your project on your development machine, copy the app to the VM, and you can test your app on the VM.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk Sometimes it's hard to pinpoint a bug without stepping through the code.

Comment: @AndyHin I know of no easier alternative than to use a VM. Xcode does not provide simulators for older OS X versions like it does for iOS.